# What are these extra /Zone.Identifier files created during Windows Remote Desktop file transfer?

Tags: windows, pdf, filesystem, remote-desktop, microsoft

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Installs [Windows Remote Desktop client for mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac)
2. Connect to a Windows 10 server, mounting a local folder over the connection
3. On the remote server, copy a pdf (e.g. `my_file.pdf` from a remote folder to the mounted Mac folder
4. Look at the mounted Mac folder locally on the Mac

## Observed behavior

The pdf I copied is there.

A second file with the same name plus `/Zone.Identifier` is there. (i.e. `my_file.pdf/Zone.Identifier` (despite the slash, that's one file name.)

The contents when viewed in a text editor is:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

## Issue

One Drive cannot sync files with slashes in their file name, so I get lots of errors whenever I do this, and I have to manually delete each one.

## Questions

- What is this file?
- What put it there? Was it the remote desktop client?
- Why doesn't it go away when I close the connection?
- Why doesn't it happen for `.txt` files?
- How do I avoid creating such a file?

Comment: This is actually a Windows issue, not Mac - this looks useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496697/what-is-zone-identifier On the Mac to delete them you have to change the `/` to a `:` ref https://superuser.com/questions/629954/osx-cant-remove-or-hide-filename-extension-zone-identifier

Comment: @Tetsujin - actually it is a `:` - Finder just shows colons in filesnames as `/`.

Comment: @lx07 - Yes, that's what I meant really; I guess I just over-simplified.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Windows: killing the Zone.Identifier NTFS alternate data stream](https://wiert.me/2011/11/25/windows-killing-the-zone-identifier-ntfs-alternate-data-stream-from-a-file-to-prevent-security-warning-popup/) the [Zone.Information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/6e3f7352-d11c-4d76-8c39-2516a9df36e8) is:

> The Zone.Identifier NTFS alternate data stream (ADS) is appended to Internet downloads by browsers, and inserted by most decompressors when expanding such downloads.

`ZoneID=3` means it was downloaded from Internet zone (as opposed to Local Intranet etc) .  Different zones are detailed in this Microsoft document [About URL Security Zones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537183(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

It is **not** a function of the file type it is metadata indicating the files provenance.

---

For example on Windows I created a new file `Doc1.pdf` in Word and downloaded a flight boarding pass `Test.pdf` from the internet.

```
PS C:\PDFtest> ls

    Directory: C:\PDFtest

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       27/12/2019     09:51          25598 Doc1.pdf
-a----       10/11/2019     14:24          21784 Test.pdf
```

Only the downloaded file contains a *Zone.Identifier* stream.

```
PS C:\PDFtest> Get-Item * -Stream zone*

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\PDFtest\Test.pdf:Zone.Identifier
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\PDFtest
PSChildName   : Test.pdf:Zone.Identifier
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\PDFtest\Test.pdf
Stream        : Zone.Identifier
Length        : 151

PS C:\PDFtest>
```

If you then copy these files to mac the stream data is converted to a file but only in the case that there was some.  This is because the filesystem (APFS) does not support streams (and indeed Windows doesn't necessarily know what filesystem it is).

```
A1398% cd ~/Downloads/PDFTest
A1398% ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x   4 hali  staff    128 Dec 27 09:11 .
drwx------+ 28 hali  staff    896 Dec 27 09:11 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 hali  staff  25598 Dec 27 09:51 Doc1.pdf
-rw-r--r--@  1 hali  staff  21784 Nov 10 14:24 Test.pdf
-rw-r--r--@  1 hali  staff    151 Nov 10 14:24 Test.pdf:Zone.Identifier
```

Note that if you check with `ls` the name is not *FileName.pdf/Zone.Identifier* it is *FileName.pdf:Zone.Identifier* - it is just macOS displays `:` as `/` in Finder. This is the same name as seen in Windows using Powershell `Get-Item -Stream` above or as mentioned in the link as seen using Nirsoft [AlternateStreamView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html)

[image: AlternateStreamView]

The contents are whatever were in this NTFS stream. In my case it also contains the website I downloaded it from - the pdf was a flight ticket and has the airline name.

```
A1398% cat Test.pdf:Zone.Identifier
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
ReferrerUrl=https://booking.nouvelair.com/web/Itinerary.xhtml
HostUrl=https://booking.nouvelair.com/web/generatePDFServlet
```

---

If you are not interested in this information you can remove the ADS on Windows as described in the above link:

> This batch file kills  the Zone.Identifier NTFS alternate data stream using the [SysInternals streams tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams):
>
> ```
> @echo off
>   if !%1!==!! goto :end
>   :: use caret before pipe to hide the pipe from the outermost command in the batch file
>   for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%d in (`streams.exe %1 ^| find "Zone.Identifier:$DATA"`) do (
>     goto :kill
>   )
>   goto :end
> :kill
>   streams -d %1
> :end
> ```

Alternatively you can remove them on macOS after copying using `rm` (adjusting the directory)

```
rm ~/Downloads/PDFTest/*:Zone.Identifier
```

Comment: That script looks like it should work, but it doesn't. I saved it to a `.bat` file, and downloaded the `streams64.exe` file, then renamed it to `streams.exe` in the same directory. When I ran `./fix.bat` in powershell the process exits without printing anything, looking like success. But the same behavior remains.

Is there any way to just tell Firefox not to create the file in the first place? (e.g. `about:config`)

Comment: @falsePockets - You could try powershell `dir * | Unblock-File` to remove them from specific directory (see [How to Remove Zone.Identifier from Multiple Files Quickly in Windows](https://www.trishtech.com/2018/12/how-to-remove-zone-identifier-from-multiple-files-quickly-in-windows/) or turn off creation in gpedit.msc option *Do not preserve zone information in file attachments* (see this ask ubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/144011) - option is the same in Windows 10).